# How do I get a dump of all extended attributes for a file?

Tags: linux, files, xattr

Getfattr dumps a listing of extended attributes for a selected file.

However, `getfattr --dump filename`  only to dumps the `user.*` namespace and not the `security.*`, `system.*`, and `trusted.*` namespaces. Generally, there are no user namespace attributes unless you attached one to a file manually.

Yes I know I can get the SELinux information by using `getfattr -n security.selinux filename`.  In this case, I know the specific identification of the extended attribute.

I have tried this as the root user.  I'd assume that the root user with full capabilities is able to access this information.  But you only get the user.* namespace dump.

The question is how can I easily get a full dump of all the extended attribute namespaces of a file without knowing the names of all the keys in all the namespaces?

Comment: and "lsattr" doesn't suffice?  (see "man chattr" in order to decode the long attribute string)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I hate to do this but the answer is (after more research):

```
 getfattr -d -m - file
```

I apparently missed this in my reading of the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html):

> **-m** *pattern*, **--match**=*pattern*
>
> Only include attributes with names matching the regular expression *pattern*. [...]
>   Specify  "-" for including all attributes.

Comment: I was using `getfattr -d -m '' file` for that, I wasn't aware `-` was a special case, but it looks like it's been like that ever since the feature was added (initially as the `-r` option). A shame. One needs to use `-m '[-]'` to search for attributes that contain `-`.