# ntfs-3g - getfattr shows only user namespace

Tags: mount, ntfs, alpine-linux, xattr, ntfs-3g

I have mounted my NTFS-HDD to Alpine Linux with the following mount options in fstab

```
UUID=4038A92D38A92340 /1TB ntfs defaults,nofail,utf8 0 0
```

when I use `getfattr -d --match="-" myfile`

I don't see any system/trusted/etc. namespace attributes...

However when I use `getfattr -h -e hex -n system.ntfs_attrib_be myfile` it shows me the value

Is this an Alpine Linux related issue or am I using it wrong?

Thanks for any help

Alpine Linux: 3.16.1

```
getfattr 2.5.1 -- get extended attributes
Usage: getfattr [-hRLP] [-n name|-d] [-e en] [-m pattern] path...
  -n, --name=name         get the named extended attribute value
  -d, --dump              get all extended attribute values
  -e, --encoding=...      encode values (as 'text', 'hex' or 'base64')
      --match=pattern     only get attributes with names matching pattern
      --only-values       print the bare values only
  -h, --no-dereference    do not dereference symbolic links
      --one-file-system   skip files on different filesystems
      --absolute-names    don't strip leading '/' in pathnames
  -R, --recursive         recurse into subdirectories
  -L, --logical           logical walk, follow symbolic links
  -P  --physical          physical walk, do not follow symbolic links
      --version           print version and exit
      --help              this help text
```

Sources I have been through:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/1008370/getfattr-to-list-all-attributes-of-the-files-in-the-folder

https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/Using-Extended-Attributes

[Why doesn't `getfattr -d` show anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180019/why-doesnt-getfattr-d-show-anything)

[How do I get a dump of all extended attributes for a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300168/how-do-i-get-a-dump-of-all-extended-attributes-for-a-file)

https://linux.die.net/man/8/vfs_acl_xattr

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619614/how-to-check-for-hidden-files-folders-on-ntfs-partition-using-python-on-linux

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html